# Find rows where one field is greater than another one

Tags: sql, sqlite

My SQL is a bit rusty. I'm not been able to find a way to retrieve rows where one value is greater than the other one. For example, I have the following row:

```
{
    ROWID       1,
    CreatedAt   2013-08-03 10:10:23:344,
    UpdatedAt   2013-08-03 11:10:23:344,
}
```

I would like to perform the query 'select all rows where 'UpdatedAt' is greater than 'CreatedAt' and match rows such the one above. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specify the desired columns between the `SELECT` and `FROM` and your predicates after the `WHERE`.

```
SELECT ROWID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt FROM TableName WHERE UpdatedAt > CreateAt;
```

Remember with SQL that if all of the predicates in your query do not evaluate to `True` in some way, the row will not return.

Comment: Awesome! In the interest of good etiquette it'd be super if you accepted one of the helpful answers.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try

```
Select *
From table 
where CreatedAt < UpdatedAt
```