# Find queryset where one field is greater than another one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have model `Shop`, I want to get all shops which `time_open`(opening time) is more than `time_closed`(closing time). For example 23:00:00 is more than 07:00:00 (Shop_2(Night shift shop)).

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    time_open = models.TimeField()
    time_closed = models.TimeField()
```

for example i have two objects:

```
shop_1 = {
    "time_open": "08:00:00",
    "time_closed": "22:00:00"
}

shop_2 = {
    "time_open": "23:00:00",
    "time_closed": "07:00:00"
}
```

My goal is to output queryset in which `shop_2` would be.
These timestamps in these objects only for visual example, i want to do it without putting any data in `sql query`. I want to achive this by comparing `time_open` and `time_closed` fields.

I found similar question in pure `SQL`:

[Find rows where one field is greater than another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035412/find-rows-where-one-field-is-greater-than-another-one)

My goal is to do it with `Django ORM`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django QuerySet: filter by the value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491884/django-queryset-filter-by-the-value-of-another-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at django's [F objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters), it allows you to filter objects based on their field values.

```
from django.db.models import F
Shop.objects.filter(time_open__gt=F('time_closed'))
```